# How to change the Color of the Status Bar in iOS when using shell

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using `Xamarin Forms v4.0.0.425677`. When I use the shell, I set the BackgroundColor to `#ff3A2E`, and it's not working in iOs.

```
<code>
public AppShell()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    SetTabBarBackgroundColor(this, Color.FromHex("#D9D9D9"));
    SetTabBarTitleColor(this, Color.FromHex("#FF3A2E"));
    SetTabBarUnselectedColor(this, Color.FromHex("#FF3A2E"));
    SetBackgroundColor(this, Color.FromHex("#FF3A2E"));
}
</code>
```

it looks like there's a cover layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For iOS you can try edit keys the `Info.plist` file, they might look like this:

```
<key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
<string>UIStatusBarStyleLightContent</string>
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
```

Comment: it's work to the tabbedpage. but in shell, it's not good. in iOs like this https://drive.google.com/open?id=1PK4q-eKcWy84mJg9le6ZNG61Vtu-T9na, in android like this https://drive.google.com/open?id=10G-o01M2wVbtld6USGHUrK_eQz3vOAJW, top and body backgroundcolor is ff3a2e, but it's not same

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround mentioned [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/383797/#Comment_383797) from this [bug report](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/6298)

Set

```
UINavigationBar.Appearance.Translucent = false;
```

in your `AppDelegate.cs` file